# Windows Store App: Performance of JSON parser

Tags: json, performance, parsing, windows-store-apps

There are many possibilities to parse a `JSON` in context of a Windows Store App. 
Regardless in which language (`C#`, `JavaScript` or `C++`).

For example: .NET 4.5 `JsonObject` and `DataContractJsonSerializer`, JavaScript `Json parser`  or an extern one like `Json.NET`.

Does anybody know something about that?

I only read good things about Json.NET's performance.
But are they true and play that a role for JSON's which include datasets of 100k `JSON` objects? Or the user won't notice a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only have experience using Json.NET ... works just fast and great! I also used the library in enterprise-projects - i never got disappointed!

Comment: Hey Alexander, thanks for your answer. Soon i'll to try to do some small performance tests, then i will post it here. But i think you are right.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, and FWIW, I've been collecting recently some new JSON parsing / deserialization performance data that can be observed over various JSON payload "shapes" (and sizes), when using four JSON librairies, there:

https://github.com/ysharplanguage/FastJsonParser#Performances

(.NET's out-of-the-box JavaScriptSerializer vs. JSON.NET vs. ServiceStack vs. JsonParser)

Please note:

1. these figures are for the full .NET only (i.e., the desktop / server tier; *not* mobile devices)
2. I was interested in getting new benchmark figures about parsing / deserialization performances only (i.e., *not* serialization)
3. finally, I was also especially interested (although not exclusively) in figures re: strongly typed deserialization use cases (i.e., deserializing into POCOs)

'Hope this helps,